# undefined is not a function(evaluating '_this2.AlertButton()')?

Tags: react-native

*I create touchableopacity for every item in map. it works well but when I give function to TouchableOpacity like below, it gives me error which is on title. How can I fix this ?*

*it gives error when I write this.AlertButton()*

```
{section.subcategory.map((item, key) => (        
          <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>this.AlertButton()}>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <View style={styles.separator} />
          </View>
        ))}
```

**This is my alert function :**

```
AlertButton() {
     const number = 'TelNo';
  Alert.alert(
      '',
      'Test',
      [
        {text: 'NO'},
        {text: 'Yes', onPress: () => Linking.openURL(`tel:${number}`)},
      ],
    );
  }
```

*Here is render. And my map function which is above is in `renderContent`*

```
 render() {
      CONTENT2 =[];
    CONTENT2 = this.state.fromPage1;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={{height: this.state.yuksek, width: this.state.genis, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',position:'absolute'}}>
        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color:'#856F6F'}}>Yukarıdaki menü butonlarına tıklayınız.</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{height: this.state.yuksek2, width: this.state.genis2, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color:'#856F6F'}}>String</Text>
      </View>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{}}>
          <Accordion
            activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
            sections={CONTENT2}
            touchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
            expandMultiple={false}
            renderHeader={this.renderHeader}

            renderContent={this.renderContent}
            duration={400}
            onChange={this.setSections}
          />
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={{height:85, width:85,position:'absolute',bottom:5,right:5}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1}} onPress={() => this.AlertButton()}>
            <ImageBackground source={require('../../image/phoneCall.png')} style={{flex:1}}>
            </ImageBackground>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post full code of the component?

Comment: It is so long, I ll  share what I can

Comment: ok then, share the full render method

Comment: I shared my render

Comment: I've posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the following line

`renderContent={this.renderContent}`

to

`renderContent={this.renderContent.bind(this)}`

because when you are using the class method directly as callback then its not definitely bound to its class when called from inside the component

Comment: Oh my god thx so much man it worked!. But I dont understand why this work when we write '.bind(this)' ?

Comment: because when you are using the class method directly as callback then its not definitely bound to its class when called from inside the component

Comment: so you've to tell js that what to use as `this` inside the function

Comment: Thx for explanation ! :)